# Accessing multiple hosts via SSH on the same public IP

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I have an issue in which I want to connect to a different host computer that exists on the same public IP (Say, `82.90.233.234`). Are both forwarded to the same port? For example, I connect my Raspberry pi using `pi@82.90.233.234`, which I can do easily. But I also have a desktop I want to access via SSH at a different `desktop@82.90.233.234`. 
Is there a way that is can be accomplished?

Disclaimer: Those are not actual IPs.

Comment: No. You cannot do this.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, I connect my Raspberry pi using pi@82.90.233.234, which I can do easily. But I also have a desktop I want to access via SSH at a different desktop@82.90.233.234. Is there a way that is can be accomplished?

If you are actually using different usernames as in your example, you could have one computer listening for ssh connections @ 82.90.233.234, and for user `pi` spawn a shell session and for user `desktop` automatically spawn an ssh session to your desktop host.

You could set up port forwarding so that the default port 22 would be your raspberry pi, but connecting to port 2200 would forward to an ssh server on your desktop.  You could set up aliases in your local `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host pi
Hostname 82.90.233.234
User pi

Host desktop
Hostname 82.90.233.234
User desktop
Port 2200
```

With this in place, you could `ssh pi` or `ssh desktop` and ssh would pick the remote username and remote port from your configuration file.